# what does "|" in a numpy type string mean?

Tags: python, numpy

Many of the examples of dtype strings in the numpy documentation feature a leading `|` character, for example `'|S10'` near the top of [the structured arrays page](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html) in the numpy manual, but neither [the structured arrays page](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html) nor the [data type objects reference](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html) seem to explain what this `|` means.  What does `|` mean in this context and where is this documented?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It refers to the [byteorder](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.byteorder.html) / [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of the dtype. In particular, the '|' indicates byte order is not applicable, such as with 8 bit numbers.